# P-value for Kendall's tau-c in R

Tags: r, statistics

I would like to know how to compute a p-value for Kendall's tau-c. The StuartTauC function in DescTools package in R can compute Kendall's tau-c and its confidence intervals but does not produce a p-value. Could anyone help me with this?

```
v1<-c(2,3,4,2,3,1,4,2,2,2,2,3,2,2,4,1,4,0,2,4,2,4,2,0,3,4,2,1,0,3,1,3,2,3,3,4,4,1,2,1,4,3,4,3,3,3,2,1,3,4,1,2,1,0,2,2,2,2,3,1,1,1,3,2,3,3)
v2<-c(15,21,58,10,32,11,48,19,17,27,3,41,16,34,5,8,29,10,13,20,31,33,8,2,29,11,9,11,11,11,2,10,21,37,3,13,15,17,11,18,7,14,17,2,20,18,22,2,42,14,15,17,31,24,11,19,7,6,31,16,17,23,22,10,15,24)
```

[StuartTauC output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zG0kP.png)

Answer (score 1):

There are two possibilities to get the p-value.

First, if you have an n less than maybe 10, you should get the exact distribution of tau assuming no difference between factors (Null hypothesis), and the get the p-value.

For bigger values of n, you can approximate using the normal distribution (assuming the same null hypothesis), that will have an asymptotic variance equal to (check [here](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statugfreq/63124/PDF/default/statugfreq.pdf) in page 1739).

If you add the code maybe I could help you more.

*aded*

If you want a p-value, assuming that you are testing that the tau_c is equal to 0 vs. tau_c is distinct to 0, we can do this:

```
v1<-c(2,3,4,2,3,1,4,2,2,2,2,3,2,2,4,1,4,0,2,4,2,4,2,0,3,4,2,1,0,3,1,3,2,3,3,4,4,1,2,1,4,3,4,3,3,3,2,1,3,4,1,2,1,0,2,2,2,2,3,1,1,1,3,2,3,3)
v2<-c(15,21,58,10,32,11,48,19,17,27,3,41,16,34,5,8,29,10,13,20,31,33,8,2,29,11,9,11,11,11,2,10,21,37,3,13,15,17,11,18,7,14,17,2,20,18,22,2,42,14,15,17,31,24,11,19,7,6,31,16,17,23,22,10,15,24)
tauc_value <- StuartTauC(v1,v2,conf.level = 0.95)
# where the standar error will be aproximately equal to:
s_e <- (tauc_value[3] - tauc_value[1])/1.96 # (Upper bound - tauc)/1.96
# so the p-value will be:
2*pnorm(tauc_value[1],mean=0,sd=s_e,lower.tail = FALSE)
```

That will give us:

```
0.03134354
```

So due to the evidence and if we use a significance level of 5%, will be rejecting the null hypothesis.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. n is 66. I have included the data for two variables in my question.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: I compared this method --- not in any systematic way --- using `DescTools::KendallTauB()` to the results from `cor.test(..., method="kendall")` (which reports a *p*-value for Kendall *tau*-b).  The *p*-values were generally reasonably close.  I would imagine, then, that this work reasonably well for *tau*-c.  It would be helpful if someone knows a way to match the *p*-value more precisely.

Answer (score 0):

The formula for computing the p-value for the StuartTauC assumes that the correlation is positive. To also produce correct p-values in the case of a negative correlation, the absolute value of the tauc_value should be used. Thus:

```
p_value <- 2*pnorm(abs(tauc_value[1]),mean=0,sd=s_e,lower.tail = FALSE)
```