# Is there a package for Kendall's Tau C in R?

Tags: r, correlation

I need to calculate the correlation between interval scale data and ordinal scale data, the latter has ties. The possible values are very different (the first data is the D-Score from an IAT, the second ranges from 1 to 7 on one question similar to a Likert item)

I tried using Spearman's Rho (from stats.cor.test) first, but it throws a warning that I don't want to ignore:

```
Warning message:
In cor.test.default(relev_f$Index_D4_nIAT_m, relev_f$ios_f, method = "spearman") :
  Cannot compute exact p-value with ties
```

After research the appropriate method in this case is Kendall's Tau C. In the DescTools package there is an option to compute Tau C, but it does not offer the p-value. Are there any options apart from calculating *p* manually (as done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51918648/p-value-for-kendalls-tau-c-in-r))?

Edit:

Kendall from cor.test produces the same warning, as it can't handle ties:

```
Warning message:
In cor.test.default(relev_f$Index_D4_nIAT_m, relev_f$ios_f, method = "kendall") :
  Cannot compute exact p-value with ties
```

Comment: Is there some reason you can't use `cor.test(method = 'kendall')`?

Comment: @jdobres edited the question

Comment: That's a warning, not an error. The function will still return a result, but is warning you that the p-value may be inexact. The Spearman and Kendall tests first rank the observations before computing the test statistic. If there are observations with identical values (as there surely would be with ordinal data), then the test does not have an exact way to resolve the ties in the ranks. The result is still valid.

Comment: I know that. But would Kendall C not still provide a more accurate result, as it is exactly for those cases, or is it negligible? If so, why does the C-Version exist?

Comment: Kendall Tau-c is also called Stuart-Kendall tau-c and is available as `StuartTauC()` in package `DescTools`.

Comment: @dcarlson I am aware of that, but that does not calculate the p-value.

Comment: Greetings! Please share a reproducible dataset as shown here: https://youtu.be/3EID3P1oisg

Comment: @ShawnHemelstrand I am sorry, but why? I am asking for the existence of a package. I can produce a dataset, but I am not asking for troubleshooting, I want to know if there is a package that gets me the Kendall's Tau C p value without having to do the math myself.

Comment: Sorry i misread your question. I can see now your question is more about finding a package or function.

Comment: @finntastic, have you found solutions for calculating the p value for Tau-c?

Comment: @teppo, Sorry, nope. Good luck!